# Change button "Choose file" text to file name

Tags: javascript, image, file, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to customize the "Choose file" button for a file picker. For indicating that a file was selected I want the "Choose file" text to be changed to the file's name. This is what I tried:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
{
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
        labelVal = label.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
    {
        var fileName = '';
        if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
        else
            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

        if( fileName )
            label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
        else
            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
    });
});
```

but it is not working, nothing gets changed after a file is selected.

Comment: You don't need to do that, it's done by default.

Comment: For security reasons the file input element does not have much functionality to change. You will need to mimic the looks and use events to transfer events to the real (hidden) file input.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button style="display:block;width:120px; height:30px;" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">File Name</button>
  <input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: You want to transfer more events then just the `onclick`. Sometimes people do use keyboard instead of mouse. If you don't use a button you might have to think about making things focusable too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fileBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.file-block')
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-select-file')

;[...buttons].forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.onclick = function () {
    btn.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="file"]').click()
  }
})

;[...fileBlocks].forEach(function (block) {
  block.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = function () {
    const filename = this.files[0].name

    block.querySelector('.btn-select-file').textContent = filename
  }
})
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-block">
  <button class="btn-select-file">Select Image 1</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
<br>
<div class="file-block">
  <button class="btn-select-file">Select Image 2</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: I try your code, but in javascript code, Netbeans give me some errors:

Comment: "Expected an aperand but found" in first 2 rows for "const" next for this "[...buttons]" and "Expected eof but found" for "})". I try repair it but nothing works.